# Disable all services, except ssh

Tags: linux, service, systemd, maintenance

How can I disable all services except ssh on modern (systemd based) linux distributions?

I need to implement a **maintenance mode**.

All these services need to be down:

- postgres
- postfix
- apache
- cups
- cron
- dovecot

But ssh must not be shut down, since this gets used to do tasks during the maintenance mode.

Of course I could write a shell script which loops over a list of services which I would like to disable. But this feels like I reinventing something which already exists, but which I don't know up to now.

Comment: What type of tasks? Why do you need this?

Comment: @user430214 I updated the question. I added: 
Of course I could write a shell script which loops over a list of services which I would like to disable. But this feels like I reinventing something which already exists, but which I don't know up to now.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This sounds a lot like *runlevels*, replaced with [*targets*](http://landoflinux.com/linux_runlevels_systemd.html) in Systemd. So, instead of writing a script that starts and stop a list of services, you could create a new `maintenance.target` containing only the services necessary, like SSH. Of course, SSH is not quite useful without networking, so in this example a simple `emergency-net.target` is modified to include SSH.

```
[Unit]
Description=Maintenance Mode with Networking and SSH
Requires=maintenance.target systemd-networkd.service sshd.service
After=maintenance.target systemd-networkd.service sshd.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

Then, you could enter your maintenance mode using

```
# systemctl isolate maintenance.target
```

and back

```
# systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It shows me that asking is useful, even if you think there is no nice answer except writing a dirty shell script. The emergency-net.target is a simple and elegant solution - great :-)

Comment: It certainly is, as it also takes care of all the dependencies, and you don't need to update your script every time you install a new service.

Comment: Could you please post what the maintenance.target file looks like? The above isn't working for me and I wonder if it's something I'm getting wrong in maintenance.target.

Comment: @chilicheech: Sorry for the late reply. You can take any suitable `.target` from `/lib/systemd/system` and modify your desired `maintenance.target` from that. It seems e.g. Debian 10 doesn't have the `emergency-net.target` used here anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the excellent answer of *@Esa*, on Debian 10, you have the file `rescue-ssh.target` to disable all services, **except** ssh and networking:

> **/lib/systemd/system/rescue-ssh.target**

```
[Unit]
Description=Rescue with network and ssh
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=network-online.target ssh.service
After=network-online.target ssh.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

So now, you can proceed as fallows:

#### 1. Enter in the *maintenance mode*:

`systemctl isolate rescue-ssh.target` (only ssh and networking)

#### 2. Check the *maintenance mode*:

`lsof -i:1-65535` (and you will only see the port of the ssh running)

#### 3. Exit from the *maintenance mode*:

`systemctl isolate multi-user.target` (and *everything* is back again)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, thanks. I'm having trouble getting it to work on CentOS 7. I realise that the file should be placed in /usr/lib/systemd/system/rescue-ssh.target and should use sshd instead of ssh. Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 3):

First list your services and search for their corresponding systemd-names.

Then build a list and stop each list member to enter maintenance, start each member after maintenance.

Comment: Why not just use `systemctl isolate`?

Comment: @ChrisDown I posted an answer about that.