# Restart all services in Linux without rebooting kernel?

Tags: systemd, reboot

I have remote machine that has encrypted drives thus each full reboot requires physical access to machine. Machine just experienced issues with lack of disk space so part of running services crashed / entered weird malfunction states. I'd like to "soft reboot" machine without actually rebooting entire kernel to avoid remounting drives and necessity to enter passphrase.

OS is using `systemd` for services management and kernel 4.9.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123678

Comment: @anx it uses *full* disk encryption. By full I mean including `GRUB` and `/boot` partition. Only stage1 bootloader saved in MBR is not encrypted. So system asks for passphrase twice - for the first time before even GRUB launches and second time during initramfs. So the only way to do this remotely would be physical remote KVM console. I saw link you mentioned but it uses `init` which is not really "systemd way" to do this since init is just some backwards-compatibility trick since `systemd` got introduced..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used with mixed success (these shortcuts are "[available for compatibility only](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/telinit.html)")

```
init 1; init 3
```

Which, nowadays typically translates to this:

```
systemctl isolate rescue; systemctl isolate default
```

Which kills everything except services that are deemed essential or part of the targets specified - systemd still provides targets that roughly mimic part of what runlevels used to to.

> **systemctl isolate UNIT**
>
> Start the unit specified on the command line and its dependencies and stop all others, unless they have IgnoreOnIsolate=yes (see systemd.unit(5)). If a unit name with no extension is given, an extension of ".target" will be assumed. - [man 1 systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)

The reason I do not quite like to recommend this, is exactly the killing part:

> This is similar to changing the runlevel in a traditional init system.
>   The isolate command will immediately stop processes that are not
>   enabled in the new unit, **possibly including the graphical environment
>   or terminal you are currently using.** - [man 1 systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)

I tried it on Ubuntu and figured i preferred if `ssh.service` and `network.target` were part of my `rescue.target`. Because it sure is safer if [only services except ssh and its networking dependencies](https://serverfault.com/a/885131/250204) were restarted.

**Because if something goes wrong while activating rescue.target, the command above might otherwise both kill my session and fail to bring everything back up.**

Comment: Thanks for `systemd` variant of procedure. `screen` is usually immune to killing ssh sessions and all other kinds of weird automatic kills. I doubt isolate would somehow destroy `screen` bash session, especially if it belongs to *root* user. I witnessed `screen` shell surviving really hardcore system failures.

Comment: If *systemd* locks up during the operation (I actually witnessed that before), *screen* surviving may be of very little help to you. Because, well, ssh sessions do not survive certain network interface changes.

Answer (score 3):

Since `systemd` v254 there is a `soft-reboot.target` which does userspace "reboot":

```
systemctl soft-reboot
```

which seems to be well-suited for this kind of tasks. It avoids the full-blown killing spree of regular shutdown procedure and allows abidance of some resources.